# How to fade out text when it is about to move out of visual range?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fade in and out text when it is about to move out of visual range? Maybe the question is a little bit vague, but what I mean is this:

[image: fade in or out when text is to be out of visual range]

How do I achieve that? Perhaps with jQuery or something?

Comment: You can achieve this using pure CSS, by creating a layer over the text, and using gradients: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing this. The easiest is to put a gradient (white to transparent) image right at the top of the text div so that it covers anything that goes off the top.

You can also use a CSS gradient and place it at the top. Something like:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

This was generated with this useful tool: [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Make sure to have the element containing the gradient fixed within the page in the case of having the whole page scroll, or fixed at the top of another scrollable div in the case that you only want the text to scroll.

Comment: This is CSS3, which is not supported by all browsers. But in my opinion, the webbrowsers must support CSS3 very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This is for horizontal scrolling, but it might help:

http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/recreating_the_fade_scrolling_text_marquee_on_twitter

It uses two gradually transparent images superimposed on the edges to cause the text behind it to fade out:

> "They have placed two PNG images that fade from 100% opaque to 100% transparent."